# How to apply a custom function to pair wise elements of an array in parallel?

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, dask

I have an array and I want to compare each element with every other element and build a cross comparison table. It can be easily implemented by nested for loops, but it's computation time increases exponentially with input array size, so I want to implement a parallel processing approach reduce time consumption at larger sizes.

I have an array, like `a = [1,2,3]` and I want to apply a custom function like:

```
def add_two_numbers(x,y):
     return x+y
```

A simple nested for loop implementation would be like:

```
array = [1,2,3]
matrix = np.zeros([3,3])
for i, one_element in enumerate(array):
    for j, other_element in enumerate(array):
        matrix[i][j] = add_two_numbers(one_element, other_element)
```

With the output being:

```
>>> matrix
    1   2   3
______________
1 | 2   3   4
2 | 3   4   5
3 | 4   5   6
```

What would be a good approach to apply parallel processing in python for large array sizes?
I used the process class in python multiprocessing library to create n processes for an n element array, but every process opens up a file at the backend and after 1024 parallel processes I get a "Too many open files" exception. And I have to make the matrix a global variable, so that every process updates a specific element.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def add_two_numbers_process(one_element, array, i):
    global matrix
    for j, other_element in enumerate(array):
        matrix[i][j] = add_two_numbers(one_element, other_element)
    return

processes = []
for i, one_element in enumerate(array):
    p = mp.Process(target=add_two_numbers_process, args=(one_element, array, i))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

I also used the Pool class, but that is taking 1000 times more time than the process class, which doesn't seem feasible.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def add_two_numbers_pool(one_element, array, i):
    row = [0 for x in range(len(array))]
    for j, other_element in enumerate(array):
        row[j] = add_two_numbers(one_element, other_element)
    return row

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
matrix = [pool.apply(add_two_numbers_pool, args=(one_element, array, i)) for i, one_element in enumerate(array)]
pool.close()
```

I can't think of an approach using dask distributed. Could dask distributed prove helpful in this case?

Comment: if you're purely CPU bound, then there's little purpose having many more processes than the number of CPUs/cores available.  could you post your multiprocessing code (by editing the question), there are a lot of details that can make the difference between a slow algorithm and a fast one

Comment: before jumping the gun to parallel processing, can you perhaps vectorize your function instead?

Comment: @Sam Mason done

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to compare each element with every other element and build a cross comparison table." Would this suffice: `x = np.array([[1,2,3]])`, `y = np.array([[3,2,1]])` and `x > y.T`? Should be a lot faster than looping as @ParitoshSingh mentions

Comment: @Dan Actually x and y are arrays of strings, and I want to apply a custom function

Comment: you're getting zero benefits from using a `Pool` if you're using `apply`, try using `map`

Comment: @HasanShaukat the point is the details of your custom function are important. You still might be able to vectorize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as a demo of using multiprocessing and the difference in vectorised vs not, we can start by defining/pulling in shared code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import numpy as np

def add_two_numbers(x,y):
     return x+y

# use a large number of values so processing takes some measurable amount of time
values = np.arange(3001)
```

we can then do your naive thing:

```
result = np.empty([len(values)]*2, values.dtype)
for i, x in enumerate(values):
    for j, y in enumerate(values):
        result[i,j] = add_two_numbers(x, y)
```

which takes ~3.5 seconds on my laptop.  we can then move this to using `multiprocessing` `Pool`with:

```
def process_row(x):
    output = np.empty_like(values)
    for i, y in enumerate(values):
        output[i] = add_two_numbers(x, y)
    return output

with Pool() as pool:
    result = np.array(pool.map(process_row, values))
```

which takes me about 1 second, we can then vectorise this in the `Pool` with:

```
def process_row_vec(x):
    return add_two_numbers(values, x)

with Pool() as pool:
    result = np.array(pool.map(process_row_vec, values))
```

which takes 0.25 seconds, and finally we can use a fully vectorised numpy version:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(values, values)
result = add_two_numbers(x, y)
```

which takes ~0.09 seconds (90ms).  I've also realised that when working with such a large number of elements these intermediate arrays (`x` and `y`) take a significant amount of computation time, and vectorising over the rows is faster:

```
result = np.empty([len(values)]*2, values.dtype)
for i, x in enumerate(values):
    result[i,:] = add_two_numbers(x, values)
```

taking 0.05 seconds (50ms).

hope these examples give you some ideas about how to implement your algorithm!

Comment: But if add_two_numbers was defined to return x+y, then how would it work on (x, values) inputs?

Comment: because `values` is a numpy array.  try running `42 + np.arange(10)`!  this is all due to Python being untyped/dynamically checked.  `add_two_numbers` just asks Python to "add" the two things it's given, it doesn't care if they're actually numbers or not

Comment: Oh, my actual function is a sentence similarity function for two strings, of the spacy library. And spacy doesn't support broadcasting unlike numpy

Comment: that would have been a useful detail to include in the question!  you're left with the two variants that just iterate naively over the elements.  the other variants were more to show the advantages you can get of not doing the naive thing.  for instance you might be able to cache intermediate values used by spacy to make things a lot faster.  I'd suggest posting another question if you get stuck, or maybe try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ once you've got something working

Comment: This question has been asked, but is not answered yet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309192/similarity-between-two-lists-of-documents

Comment: the answer looks reasonable, especially given the level of detail in the question!  what's wrong with it?